# Save sniffed packets into a variable or a file after keyboardInterrupt using scapy and python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, save, scapy, sniffing

Can someone please help me with saving sniffed packets into a file using scapy? I need to use scapy to sniff untill a keyboardInterrupt and save the sniffed packets into a pcap file, the problem is that the keyboardInterrupt makes the sniffed packets disapear, so is there a way to save the packets while sniffing? or save them into the variable even though there is an exception?

This is what I tried so far but the exeption prevented it from being saved:

```
from scapy.all import *
try:
    packets = sniff()
except KeyboardInterrupt as ki:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store them using a function

```
from scapy.all import *

packet_list = []

def storepkt(pkt):
    packet_list.append(pkt)


try:
    sniff(ptr=storepkt)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ki:
    #Here you should have access to the packet_list list and do whatever you need with them, i.e.:
    for pkt in packet_list:
        pkt.show()
```

Note that this code is for Python 2.7.